# Tutorial Using msg

Tags: ros, tutorial

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When I try to follow the tutorial step

```
$echo "int64 num" > msg/Num.msg
```

i get bash:

```
msg/Num.msg: no permission
```

Anyone has a solution to this? unfortunately i dont understand how the permission system in ubuntu works as i am newfag.

thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/214593/tutorial-using-msg/) by [Che.](https://answers.ros.org/users/23353/che./) on ROS Answers with karma: 48 on 2015-07-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You are trying to run the line `echo "int64 num" > ..` in a directory where you have no *write permissions*. You can check with the command `pwd` where you are: it's most likely something like `/opt/ros/ROSVERSION/share/..`. Basically: anything outside your own home directory (`/home/your_user_name/`) is typically off-limits for regular users.

If so, you'll want to setup a *workspace* (simply a directory where you can create your own package, in your home dir) and work from that.

See [wiki/catkin/create_a_workspace](http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/Tutorials/create_a_workspace) for some more information.

> Anyone has a solution to this? unfortunately i dont understand how the permission system in ubuntu works as i am newfag.

Then you might also benefit from reading a Linux beginner tutorial or two. It will really help you understand all the 'magic incantations' that are littered throughout the ROS tutorials & documentation.

For ROS itself, in addition to the tutorials you are already following, I'd recommend picking up a book. The wiki has a [Books](http://wiki.ros.org/Books) section which lists a few. Personally I like [A Gentle Introduction To ROS](http://wiki.ros.org/Books/AGentleIntroductiontoROS). Teaches only the basics, but is *really* gentle.

---

Edit:

> thank you gvdhoorn for your quick response and also for taking care of my other (duplicate) thread. i think my problem is as mig here describes. as i followed the tutorial i may have used sudo for creating my "beginnger_tutorials" folder. is it possible to change the permission of it afterwards?

If the `beginner_tutorials` directory is somewhere in your home directory (so not in `/opt/ros/..`), then you may fix the permissions using `sudo chown USER: -R /path/to/beginner_tutorials` (where `USER` is the name of your user). Note the `:`.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2015-07-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2015-07-27**:
as a minor addition:
You might also have no permissions if you created this file using `sudo touch msg/Num.msg`. You can check with `ls -l msg/Num.msg` what the permissions are. [See here for more info](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FilePermissions).

**Comment by [Che.](https://answers.ros.org/users/23353/che./) on 2015-07-27**:
thank you gvdhoorn for your quick response and also for taking care of my other (duplicate) thread.
i think my problem is as mig here describes. as i followed the tutorial i may have used sudo for creating my "beginnger_tutorials" folder.
is it possible to change the permission of it afterwards?

**Comment by [Che.](https://answers.ros.org/users/23353/che./) on 2015-07-27**:
that worked, thank you! have a beer on me.
so chown USER makes USER the new owner of that directory with RXW-Permissions?
can i change the status to "solved" for the thread or something like that?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-07-27**:
Yes. `chown` == CHange OWNer. The permissions are not changed, just the owner.

> can i change the status to "solved" for the thread or something like that?

Yes.